Plotly Heatmap Colorbar Displays Ticks in Incorrect Location
I'm creating a 1-line heatmap using plotly, based on this guide. In the original code, the z array is 2 dimensional, and everything works fine. But if z is 1D the tickmarks move for some reason.
Here's the original code:
def discrete_colorscale(bvals, colors):
    """
    bvals - list of values bounding intervals/ranges of interest
    colors - list of rgb or hex colorcodes for values in [bvals[k], bvals[k+1]],0<=k < len(bvals)-1
    returns the plotly  discrete colorscale
    """
    if len(bvals) != len(colors) + 1:
        raise ValueError('len(boundary values) should be equal to  len(colors)+1')
    bvals = sorted(bvals)
    nvals = [(v - bvals[0]) / (bvals[-1] - bvals[0]) for v in bvals]  # normalized values

    dcolorscale = []  # discrete colorscale
    for k in range(len(colors)):
        dcolorscale.extend([(nvals[k], colors[k]), (nvals[k + 1], colors[k])])
    return dcolorscale


bvals = [2, 15, 40, 65, 90]
colors = ['#09ffff', '#19d3f3', '#e763fa' , '#ab63fa']
dcolorsc = discrete_colorscale(bvals, colors)

bvals = np.array(bvals)
tickvals = [np.mean(bvals[k:k + 2]) for k in range(len(bvals) - 1)]  # position with respect to bvals where ticktext is displayed
ticktext = [f'<{bvals[1]}'] + [f'{bvals[k]}-{bvals[k+1]}' for k in range(1, len(bvals)-2)]+[f'>{bvals[-2]}']

z = np.random.randint(bvals[0], bvals[-1]+1, size=(20, 20))
heatmap = go.Heatmap(
  z=z, colorscale=dcolorsc, colorbar=dict(thickness=25, tickvals=tickvals, ticktext=ticktext)
)
fig = go.Figure(data=[heatmap])
fig.update_layout(width=500, height=500)
fig.show()


If we attempt to only show the 1st line of z, you'll see the ticks move up:
# ... same as above ...
heatmap = go.Heatmap(
  z=[z[0]], colorscale=dcolorsc, colorbar=dict(thickness=25, tickvals=tickvals, ticktext=ticktext)
)
fig = go.Figure(data=[heatmap])
fig.update_layout(width=500, height=500)
fig.show()



So you want to display only the data for y=0 (first line of z) and keep x/y axis range unchanged ? Or I misunderstood..

No @EricLavault, sorry for the confusion. I'm fine with how the main figure looks like, the issue is with the colorbar on the right hand side. Compare the location of ticks ("<15", "15-40", etc.) between the two figures - see how in the bottom the ticks start drifting upwards (it's most pronounced with the top tick)?
